# Error Storing Date in custom format using to_date

Tags: sql, jdbc, oracle11gr2, to-date

Aim:

1. I want to store date in database in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.
2. I have first formatted it using `DateFormat` which results in changing it to `String` datatype and then trying to convert back to date datatype by using `to_date` function but it gets stored in as `19-DEC-12` i.e `dd-MON-yy` format.

Code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
java.util.Date dob=JDateChooser.getDate();  
java.sql.Date dobloc=new java.sql.Date(dob.getTime()); 
String dobloc1=df.format(dobloc);   
String sql="INSERT INTO ADMIN.DEPARTMENT(date_of_birth) VALUES (to_date(?,'dd/MM/yyyy'))"
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);  
pst.setString(1, dobloc1);
```

Comment: Just us that `java.sql.Date` directly, you are confusing presentation format and storage format.

Answer (score 2):

Dates are not kept with the format you specify in any database (unless you use a string field) Most database systems store datetime values as a "double" value.

You should put the date into the database and worry about formatting when you are getting the data from the db or presenting it to the user.

Comment: Actually I am trying to store in a correct format because i am displaying a pure copy of my Database table on some other forms using JTable so the date formatting in which date is stored gets displayed directly. I dont want to convert Date Format on my  large number of Jtables which may make me to change the Date format again and again as my tables goes on increasing

Comment: I am not familiar with JTable but I still believe you should not worry about in which format to insert the data but rather in which format to display the data in JTable. That is because no matter what you do, database engine does not keep any information about in which format you inserted the data. It just keeps the date as a native value. But since I am not familiar with JTable, I won't insist :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding how date actually works in Oracle.
The date is not stored like "19-DEC-12" or "19/12/2012", it is stored as 7-bytes.

See [here](http://www.ixora.com.au/notes/date_representation.htm) for further details.

If you select a date column it is formatted using NLS_DATE_FORMAT.
This is the default mask used to format those 7-bytes.

Of course if you use a custom format mask like `to_char(sysdate,'YYYY MM DD')` the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT is ignored.

As I read in the above comments

> Actually I am trying to store in a correct format because i am displaying a pure copy of my Database table on some other forms using JTable so the date formatting in which date is stored gets displayed directly. I dont want to convert Date Format on my large number of Jtables which may make me to change the Date format again and again as my tables goes on increasing

I suggest you also save the specific formatting mask used to format the dates in another column in your DB-Table.
Before you display your date in the JTable you format it with this mask using `DateFormat`.